# Error 405 when angularjs makes a post request to web api

Tags: angularjs, cors, asp.net-web-api

I have Web Api service hosted on IIS (localhost:81) and my angularjs app running on IIS Express (localhost:8080) is trying to communicate with it.

The angularjs service function is as below

```
function Register(username, password) {
     var data = { "username": username, "password": password };
     var promise = $http.post('http://localhost:81/api/Account', JSON.stringify(data));
     return promise;
}
```

My Web Api service method looks like

```
public class AccountController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public bool Post(User user)
    {
        Core.DataContracts.AuthenticationResponse authResponse = Account.CreateUser(Mapper.Map<Core.DataContracts.User>(user));
        return (authResponse.Code == Core.DataContracts.ResponseCode.Created);
    }
}
```

I read on various forum that it could be to do with CORS but I have got `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` in my `web.config`

```
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

Also, I am able to make a GET request but having this issue with the POST request.

Details from Fiddler are:

```
 OPTIONS http://localhost:81/api/Account HTTP/1.1
 Host: localhost:81
 Connection: keep-alive
 Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
 Origin: http://localhost:8080
 User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/38.0.2125.101 Safari/537.36
 Access-Control-Request-Headers: accept, content-type
 Accept: */*
 Referer: http://localhost:8080/app/index.html
 Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
 Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
```

I tried making the request directly from Fiddler which results in a success

```
 POST http://localhost:81/api/Account HTTP/1.1
 User-Agent: Fiddler
 Host: localhost:81
 Content-Length: 40
 Content-Type: application/json

 {"username":"abc","password":"asasasas"}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure your POST address is correct ? HTTP 405 means that the method isn't allowed.

Comment: @GeoffreyB See the request I made directly through Fiddler, the address same but that one results in a success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix it by adding following to WebApiConfig.Register method

```
var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");
config.EnableCors(cors);
```

And removed CORS configuration from Web.config and Startup.cs